# Browser keeps "waiting for localhost"

Tags: node.js, express, time, localhost, out

in my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Do work here
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hey! It works!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am able to make the first request just fine, but every subsequent request just waits for localhost until it times out.

app.js looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');

// create our Express app
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // this is the folder where we keep our pug files
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // we use the engine pug, mustache or EJS work great too

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in public/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

the start.js file looks like this.  I should add that this is not my own code - it's part of the node.js tutorial from Wes Bos.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

// Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`        → ${err.message}`);
});

// READY?! Let's go!


// Start our app!
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your index.js file?

Comment: The code posted is the index.js file.  Sorry if I wasn't clear about that

Comment: I guess specifically, can you post your primary javascript file. The file that imports the router and calls something like `app.listen()`

Comment: Sure thing.  Included the start.js and app.js logic.

Comment: From my experience (could be wrong) you need to connect the route to the express app. It appears as though you are defining the route, the app is not aware of it. It should be more like this: [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Also, if you have an `index.js`, you can simply import the folder rather than the entire path to the file.

Comment: The app must be aware of the route though, because it's making the connection successfully at least once.  The first time I get 'Hey! It works!' printed to the browser screen.  After that, any subsequent requests just hang and eventually time out.  If I move over to another browser, again, I can make the request successfully, but only one time.

Comment: Solved the problem I was having and have posted the answer below.  Thanks for taking the time to troubleshoot this with me @CoolestNerdIII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my own problem, so I'm reporting back for anyone who may have encountered the same issue coming from the Wes Bos Node.js tutorial.

The solution was to *double check my variables.env file* - I had stupidly left arrow brackets around the username and password fields.  If you're having this issue, make sure your DATABASE environment variable looks something like this:

`DATABASE=mongodb://dang:dang@ds057833.mlab.com:57833/dang-thats-delicious`